# How to start an application with an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start an intent to start Facebook with some extras. How can I do that?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(<????>);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The email subject text");   
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check that");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Facebook Android SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android).

Answer (score 0):

There is no sure way of doing this as the actions the Facebook application responds to may change and may not be publicly known.  Here is  a way to bring up a dialog which Facebook may respond to:

```
startActivity(
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    .setType("image/png")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "")
);
```

`uri` is a reference to a PNG image on disk

Comment: My problem is that I want to set different extras according to the app chosen by the user (eg long text for facebook and short text for twitter). I tried to use ACTION_SEND but I can't find any way to intercept the app chosen. So now I'm doing my own dialog...